# How to show package explorer like structure in Swing

Tags: eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am new to Swing and Eclipse plugin development. Please help me out. The plugin has to create a sample file at a location the user selects. Does anybody know how to show up PackageExplorer like structure in Swing. Is there a component/Java class for this problem.?

Comment: Swing has a JTree. But Eclipse doesn't use Swing.

Comment: Eclipse plugins normally use SWT not Swing